# Can't push database to heroku because database is not empty error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

Hello and excuse my english

Trying to push my postgres DB to heroku with the command:

```
heroku pg:push projectDB DATABASE_URL --app my_project_app67654
```

I got the message:

```
 !    Remote database is not empty.
 !    Please create a new database, or use `heroku pg:reset`
```

Then I used the command:

```
heroku pg:reset DATABASE_URL --app my_project_app67654
```

Which returned:

```
..Done
```

Then I used heroku pg:push again and the same error ocured again and again

Just to make sure, I logged in to the heroku database after resetting with:

```
heroku pg:psql --app my_project_app67654
```

And zero relation where there.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to upload de DB to heroku doing the following

Note: Replace with the proper parameters

Backing up the local DB

```
$ pg_dump -U pg-user local-DB -f path-to-dump-file
```

Restoring the DB in heroku

```
$ heroku pg:psql -a heroku-app-name < path-to-dump-file
```

No idea about why the database is not empty error ocurred, but this worked fine for me

Comment: I just followed the instructions given by the console and it worked just fine. Maybe the bug is already solved.

Comment: CREATE EXTENSION > ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql CREATE TABLE >ERROR:  must be member of role "postgres" I encountered this error while following your command. How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

For windows to create dump DB you need execute the folowing command in cmd:

```
pg_dump -U loginDB -f "c:\dump" DB_name
```

c:\dump"- path to dump file.